# Unity C#, display a score, before deletion of a game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have been learning Unity recently and I have a problem. I'm making a top down shooter and when my tank shoots the enemy I want a score displayed in the top. But I also have a Destroy function to destroy my enemy when a bullet hits them, and it is also destroying the scoreText.

The code in my CollisionWithEnemy class

```
public class CollisionWithEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static double score = 0;
    public Text scoreText;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        Score();
        Destroy(gameObject);  
    }

    public void Score()
    {
        score += 0.5;
        if (score % 1 == 0)
        {
           Debug.Log(score);
           scoreText.text = score.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The error I get in Unity: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My question is how can I get the score to keep displaying even after a game object has been destroyed?

Comment: how are you expecting it to look if you had 5 tanks on screen would you expect all to have the score?

Comment: @BugFinder well it's just a one tank game?

Comment: why would the score be on your enemy? or is it the "enemys" score? if its the enemys score, then it would be right to die with the enemy he died.. why would he get points for dying?

Comment: In case `CollisionWithEnemy` is attached to the player tank: Write `collision.gameObject` (to refer to the enemy) instead of `gameObject` (which would refer to the player tank itself).

Comment: Do you want a score to pop up above the dead tank and fade away? If so I would create a new prefab for this score and in its script destroy itself after its animation finishes or after a set duration. Just instantiate this prefab when the tank dies as a new gameObject without a parent

Comment: Just create an object to keep your game state. Preferably a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` then the problem is likely `scoreText` did not get set. Ensure you have set this via the inspector.

Is `scoreText` childed to an object that gets destroyed? If so remove it as a child.
 Do all objects that have this script have `scoreText` set? If not you will receive errors.